# Cassandra: rpc_timeout when inserting in a new table in a cluster

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cqlsh

I am using Cassandra 2.0.3 and I drop and recreate a simple table via cqlsh by loading a file (source command). In the same file, I insert some rows in the newly created table.

About once every 3-4 tries, I get rpc_timeout on some of the inserts.
When this is the case, I always have this exception on one node of the cluster:

```
 WARN [Thread-63] 2014-05-07 10:52:39,658 IncomingTcpConnection.java (line 83) UnknownColumnFamilyException reading from socket; closing
org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find cfId=15a8520e-bb08-3a79-82a0-f735287315bf
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilySerializer.deserializeCfId(ColumnFamilySerializer.java:178)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilySerializer.deserialize(ColumnFamilySerializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowMutation$RowMutationSerializer.deserializeOneCf(RowMutation.java:304)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowMutation$RowMutationSerializer.deserialize(RowMutation.java:284)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowMutation$RowMutationSerializer.deserialize(RowMutation.java:312)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowMutation$RowMutationSerializer.deserialize(RowMutation.java:254)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageIn.read(MessageIn.java:99)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessage(IncomingTcpConnection.java:153)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.handleModernVersion(IncomingTcpConnection.java:130)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.run(IncomingTcpConnection.java:74)
```

Even if I do the INSERT direcly in cqlsh, it fails also with rpc_timeout. Usually after about one minute, the insert is successful.

My nodes are time synchronized (I use 3 VMs on my PC) and the LAN is of course super fast on all VMs are running locally.

I created the cluster by adding 2 nodes to an existing Cassandra running on a single node.
My keyspace is not using replication:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE eras
  WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
```

Here is the content of the file I use to reproduce the problem:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS erasconfig;

CREATE TABLE erasconfig (
  name text,
  category text,
  description text,
  ismodifiablebyuser int,
  value text,
  format text,
  PRIMARY KEY (name, category)
);

INSERT INTO ErasConfig (isModifiableByUser, format, name, value, category, description) VALUES (1, '', 'RECORD_IN_BASE', 'garbage', 'Path', 'Absolute path used for RECORD INPUT files');
```

This INSERT goes into the 3rd node of the cluster which is the one failing sometimes during table creation with the exception above.

Comment: Just tried after upgrading to release 2.0.7 and I had the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that schema replication is asynchronous to the create finishing.  So in a multinode cluster you need to verify that the schema changes have propagated to all the nodes before you try to use them.  The `nodetool describecluster` can be used to check if the schemas agree.  From a client you can check the system.peers table to verify that all the schema versions have updated.

Comment: Thanks for the command! Do you think I should raise a bug on Cassandra project for this?